# "Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at (path)" on eclipse 4.2.2 using Mac OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have been struggling with this issue all day now and would appreciate some help for this community.

I'm trying to get an Android project started using the Google App Engine as the backend on eclipse. I got the App Engine setup on Google's Cloud Platform and now I just need to integrate it with my Android project eclipse using Entity and Endpoints. (reading this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities)

After downloading Google's eclipse plugin for eclipse 4.2 under "Install New Software", I obtain the **appengine-java-sdk1.8.8**, but under Preferences -> Google -> AppEngine, the **sdk** is not there.
So I tried adding it, putting "(eclipse-path)/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8/)" but it says:
***Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at (Path of AppEngine SDK)***

I have been looking for a solution to this issue for all of today and so far, I've tried:

-Changing around permissions with chmod
-Installing Java SE 1.7.0_45 (the latest version) and switching the JRE back and forth from 1.6 and 1.7
-tried out both Eclipse 3.7 and 4.2.2

I am running Mac OSX Mountain Lion. Someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some points:

- The latest versions of App Engine SDK require JDK 7
- Make sure that you have the latest version of the JDK too
- Make sure there is no mismatch of 32-bit v/s 64-bit versions for OS, Eclipse and JDK.
- Try providing the `-vm` parameter in the `eclipse.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the matching ire and jdk packages like `jdk-7u45-macosx-x64 and jre-7u45-macosx-x64` and set their path on eclipse->preferences->java

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the App Engine SDK [for Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) is installed.